# Joining 3 tables and returning 0 for a column if value is not found in any of the 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have the following 3 tables.

```
 PROP_MASTER
--------------------
    BORO
    BLOCK
    LOT
    COL1
    COL2
    COL3

    TABLE2
-------------
    BORO
    BLOCK
    LOT
    COL4

    TABLE3
-------------
    BORO
    BLOCK
    LOT
    COL5
```

In one query I would like to get

```
Boro
Block
Lot
COL1
COL2
COL3
COL4 
COL5
```

However, if record doesn't exist for the same BORO,BLOCK AND LOT IN either TABLE2 COL4 should return 0 and if record doesn't exist in Table3 then COL5 SHOULD BE ZERO.

How can I join these 3 tables.

```
Select B.BORO,B.BLOCK,B.LOT,B.COL1,B.COL2,B.COL3
FROM PROP_MASTER B, TABLE2 T2, TABLE3 T3
WHERE B.BORO=T2.BORO AND B.BORO=T3.BORO AND
B.BLOCK=T2.BLOCK AND B.BLOCK=T3.BLOCK AND
B.LOT=T3.LOT AND B.LOT=T3.LOT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best best is to `LEFT JOIN` Table2 and Table3 to your `PROP_MASTER` based on the common attributes (BORO, BLOCK, and LOT), and then use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    PROP_MASTER.BORO,
    PROP_MASTER.BLOCK,
    PROP_MASTER.LOT,
    PROP_MASTER.COL1,
    PROP_MASTER.COL2,
    PROP_MASTER.COL3,
    COALESCE(TABLE2.COL4, 0) AS COL4,
    COALESCE(TABLE3.COL5, 0) AS COL5
FROM PROP_MASTER
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON
        TABLE2.BORO = PROP_MASTER.BORO
        AND TABLE2.BLOCK = PROP_MASTER.BLOCK
        AND TABLE2.LOT = PROP_MASTER.LOT
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON
        TABLE3.BORO = PROP_MASTER.BORO
        AND TABLE3.BLOCK = PROP_MASTER.BLOCK
        AND TABLE3.LOT = PROP_MASTER.LOT
```

Answer (score 0):

do union

```
select col from PROP_MASTER
union
select col from TABLE2
union
select col from TABLE3
```

Comment: This does not answer the original question, as it does not check for keys common to more than one table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
Select B.BORO,B.BLOCK,B.LOT,B.COL1,B.COL2,B.COL3,T2.COL4,T3.COL5
FROM PROP_MASTER B  
LEFT join  TABLE2 T2 ON B.BORO=T2.BORO  AND B.BLOCK=T2.BLOCK AND B.LOT=T2.LOT
LEFT join  TABLE3 T3 ON B.BORO=T3.BORO  AND B.BLOCK=T3.BLOCK AND B.LOT=T3.LOT
WHERE 
(T2.BORO IS NULL and T2.BLOCK IS NULL and T2.LOT IS NULL) OR 
(T3.BORO IS NULL and T3.BLOCK IS NULL and T3.LOT IS NULL)
```